# Android Empty List

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am trying to fill a `ListView` inside an Async Task!

```
all_items = gson.toJson(profile);
this is the rest

try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(all_items);
            JSONArray ja = object.getJSONObject("tree").getJSONArray("children");
            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object1 = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                if (object1.has("name") && object1.has("percentage")) {
                    System.out.println(object1.has("name"));//nothing gets printed
                    HashMap<String, Object> tmp = new HashMap<>();
                    tmp.put("name", object1.get("name"));
                    tmp.put("percentage", object1.get("percentage"));
                    array_list.add(tmp);

                }
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Json Array is in this format:

This new code is not outputing nothing,no lists is shown The Json is in this format

```
{
  "id": "*UNKNOWN*",
  "processed_lang": "en",
  "source": "*UNKNOWN*",
  "tree": {
    "children": [
      {
        "children": [
          {
            "category": "personality",
            "children": [
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "category": "personality",
                    "id": "Adventurousness",
                    "name": "Adventurousness",
                    "percentage": 0.6317251869427992,
                    "sampling_error": 0.0550028572
```

No Error is thrown however the list is still empty.

Comment: there are basically 3 more `children` array inside the `children` array. Your code just gets the top level children and tries to find the attributes inside it.

Comment: so hoe do I solve it? @M.WaqasPervez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are basically 3 more children array inside the children array. Your code just gets the top level children and tries to find the attributes inside it

```
try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(all_items);
        JSONArray ja = object.getJSONObject("tree").getJSONArray("children");

 for (int k = 0; k < ja.size(); k++) {
          JSONObject lvlOne = ja.getJSONObject(k);
          JSONArray lvlOneArray = lvlOne.getJSONArray("children");

          for (int j = 0; j < lvlOneArray.size(); j++) {
              JSONObject lvlTwo = lvlOneArray.getJSONObject(i);
              JSONArray lvlTwoArray = lvlTwo.getJSONArray("children");

        for (int i = 0; i < lvlTwoArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object1 = lvlTwoArray.getJSONObject(i);
            if (object1.has("name") && object1.has("percentage")) {
                System.out.println(object1.has("name"));//nothing gets printed
                HashMap<String, Object> tmp = new HashMap<>();
                tmp.put("name", object1.get("name"));
                tmp.put("percentage", object1.get("percentage"));
                array_list.add(tmp);

            }
        }
    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: in JSon array it cannot be applied to java.lang.String!

Comment: can u explain please ?

Comment: the second `.getJSONArray("children")` is marked red and says `in JSon array it cannot be applied to java.lang.String`

Comment: `getJSONArray
(int)
in JSONArray cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.String)`

Comment: can I ask you one last question?how can I get the `Adventurousness` only one time